# Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at Driver.<anonymous> (ngsw-worker.js:2353)

Tags: json, angular, angular7, angular-service-worker

I am trying to include service worker in my angular 7 application.
I used the following command for this:

```
ng add @angular/pwa
```

My lighthouse report says:

```
Current page does not respond with a 200 when offline
```

To solve the above problem from lighthouse report, i added my site url in ngsw-config.json file.

**My ngsw-config.json file:**

```
{
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**"
        ],
        "urls": [
          "https://getcoursetube.com/**"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But after that i am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at Driver.<anonymous> (ngsw-worker.js:2353)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (ngsw-worker.js:1772)
```

and lighthouse report still says Current page does not respond with a 200 when offline

Comment: The most common reason to get an error type "Unexpected toke <..." is that the response is not a json else you're receiving a errorpage.html